# Updating arrays with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Struggling to get my head round this - have tried all sorts of approaches but can't help but feel that I'm overcomplicating things.

I have a set of values stored in my MongoDB database as an array, for example:

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    users: ['Bob', 'James', 'Catherine', 'Emma']
}
```

A new array is then sent from my app to the server, e.g.

```
var newArray = ['Edward', 'Bob', 'David', 'James', 'Ellie', 'Monica']
```

What I'd like to do is update the array so that:

1. Any elements currently in the database but not in the new array are deleted
2. Any elements in both arrays are retained
3. Any elements in the new array but not in the original one are added

So the final result saved to the database should be:

```
['Bob', 'James', 'Edward', 'David', 'Ellie', 'Monica']
```

I've tried simply running

```
documents.findOneAndUpdate({ id: 1234 }, {
    $set: {  users: newArray  }
})
```

but all it does is add the new Array to the existing one, so I end up with duplicates and it doesn't remove the unwanted values - resulting in the following:

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    users: ['Bob', 'Bob', 'James', 'James', 'Catherine', 'Emma', 'David', 'Edward', 'Ellie', 'Monica']
}
```

I've also tried:

```
newArray.forEach(function(user){
    documents.findOneAndUpdate({ id: 1234 }, {
        $addToSet: { users: user }
    })
})
```

which adds the new values without duplicating existing ones, but doesn't remove the ones that aren't in the newly submitted array, i.e.:

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    users: ['Bob', 'James', 'Catherine', 'Emma', 'Edward', 'David', 'Ellie', 'Monica']
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this without a complicated series of nested loops and multiple calls to the database (which is where I seem to be headed at the moment)?

NB: For brevity, I've not included callbacks or `.exec` functions in the code above - I know that these are necessary to execute, but thought it would get a bit convoluted if I included them.

EDIT: I should also add that this is a simplified version of what I'm actually working with, but should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to use [Lodas](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#union) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try like this:

```
documents.findOne({ id: 1234 },function(doc) {
    doc.users = newArray
    doc.save()
})
```

I did it like this before, but never try with findOneAndUpdate.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was making things too complicated! Sometimes seems that there are so many different ways to do the same thing with mongoDB/mongoose that it's easy to miss the simple stuff. Anyway, thanks a million!

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding!